# Loading an external page with some external JS files using jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load an external page into a div using Jquery AJAX and that page contains lots of external jquery plugins. I am able to load the page but plugins are not working. I want to load those jquery plugins when external page is loaded through jquery AJAX. Is there any way to do it? Please provide me the link of snippet if available.

Comment: could you show me your code ..... if your loading external js then you have to check with add an extra js library file

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are doing something like this.

```
 $.get(url,data).done(function(response){
         var html = response.html;
         $('selector').append(html);
         $('carousel').init();//example of how to manually trigger a plugin
        });
```

Usually the plugins init method are called on an event, either a dom ready or dom load event, however in your case that init method is never triggered.So,
you need to manually trigger the plugins after loading the content.
In the example above once the content is loaded I have provided an example of how a plugin(here carousel) could be triggered.